# VirtueMart API Connection/web Reference

Tags: c#, api, integration, connection-string, virtuemart

I have been trying to find a way to integrate with a `Joomla` / `Virtuemart` store.

I spent hours online searching for `API` documentation and failed to find a way to start the integration.

Can anyone point me into a direction to help me get started? I am trying to integrate using `ASP.Net C#` in `Visual Studio 2010`.

Is there complete documents other then [www.vitruemart.net/api](http://www.vitruemart.net/api).

I need some kind of web reference, or even just a way to make and connection to my `Vitruemart` store, so I can start calling those methods the `API` docs referenced above.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That URL should be www.virtuemart.net/api

Comment: It doesn't work, to integrate you need to connect to a url of that store with and api user and key as far as i know, vs2010 can't make a web reference of www.virtuemart.net/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link below has an SOA Extention you install into `Joomla/Viruemart` store, then you find documentation there on how to install it, you have to create a super user in `Joomla` as a `API` key and user for this integration.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/soa-virtuemart/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/soa-virtuemart/files/1.5/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/soa-virtuemart/files/Documentation/